# Disable NFC package on Android 12

Tags: android-12, nfc

From the forum, I got lots of information about package disabling on Android. But none of this works for me. I try block the NFC package on boot:

1. `pm disable com.android.nfc`
2. `svc nfc disable`
3. `service call nfc 8`

But these commands don't work and NFC still loads and works.

What else can I do?

Comment: Does your Settings app not allow NFC to be turned off? Or is there an app which is able to (ab)use NFC without your permission, hence you are trying to get rid of NFC altogether? By the way, what errors were reported for the above commands?

Comment: Since manufacturers can and do customize their Android, could you mention the device model?

Comment: Firelord , I have 6 to 4 tunnel in myphone with two new interfaces: ipv6tnl0 and sit0. And this tunnel turn on bluetooth and NFC without my permission. I don't know  how to delete this tunnel from OS, that's why I try to block bluetooth and NFC from boot and restrict tunnel virus activity on my phone. I could disable bluetooth but NFC not. Commands does not reported any errors at all.

Comment: Andrew T. my smartphone SM-A510F (A5 2016) with custom Android 12.

Comment: I tried pm disable com.android.bluetooth and pm disable com.android.nfc again. I can't turn on bluetooth. But NFC I can turn on from Connection preferenced panel of my smartphone. Both commands shows the same result: Package com.android.bluetooth new state:disabled and Package com.android.nfc new state:disabled.